# What's the increment operator doing here and how it changes the scale?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, syntax, data-visualization, data-retrieval

What's the increment operator doing above inside the `forEach` block, specifically:

```
d3.tsv('data.tsv', (err, data) => {
  // clean the data
  data.forEach(d => {
    d.date = new Date(d.date); // x
    ++d[city]; // y`
```

And how does it change the scale?

Full code: [Scales and Axes](https://blockbuilder.org/sxywu/8045c7e4f4aebce27722e23eec960a6b)

Answer (score 2):

This kind of question (*"what is this thing doing here?"*) is sometimes hard to answer because we cannot know what was inside the author's head. But in this case I believe I have a hunch: the author is just **incorrectly** coercing the strings to numbers.

As you probably know, the TSV data is loaded and parsed as strings, so when we have numbers in the fields we have to coerce them. The most common way is, in the row function:

```
d.foo = +d.foo;
return d;
```

As you can see in this demo, if you just do `+d.foo` nothing happens with the object:

```js
const obj = {
  value: "42"
};
+obj.value;
console.log(obj)
console.log(typeof obj.value)
```

That being said, I believe the author of that code just found that, if you use a prefix increment operator, you change the object without having to return it (since `++foo` acts like `foo = foo + 1`):

```js
const obj = {
  value: "42"
};
++obj.value;
console.log(obj)
console.log(typeof obj.value)
```

And here you can see why I said *incorrectly*: the value is being increased. If you look at the data in that Blockbuilder you linked, you'll see that all the numbers for San Francisco are 1 unit bigger than the real numbers in the TSV.

Comment: This leaves me pondering all day long how to correctly convert strings to numbers without using any `=`. I am open to any screwed up expression. The race is on.

Comment: @altocumulus I thought about the comma operator as well.

Comment: When using the row function the axis was missing the top value as compared to using a prefix increment operator, why is not rendering correctly? Edited the post to add images

Comment: @user1076808 because the increment solution is incorrect: the max value is not 68, it is 67. The second image is the correct output. But if you're asking why the axis is not showing the number 67 this is a **completely different** question. I rolled back your edit.